# I was getting ready & I was joking

Tags: present-continuous

Could you explain why in bold is necessary to use Past Continuous, not Past Simple. Because of "to get ready" and "to joke" are always processes or why?

> Sorry I’m late. My phone rang three times while **I was getting ready** to go out.

> Sorry I’m late. My phone rang three times while **I got ready** to go out. *(Is it not correct?)*

> When I first told Tom what happened, he didn’t believe me. He thought that **I was joking**.

> When I first told Tom what happened, he didn’t believe me. He thought that **I joked**. *(Is it not correct?)*

TIA

Comment: [Question form: Why does x have to be used? and: Can you explain why x is used in y?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different uses for past continuous:

- Interrupted Action in the Past
- Specific Time as an Interruption
- Parallel Actions
- Atmosphere
- Repetition and Irritation with "Always"

In your first example the action "getting ready" was interrupted by the action "the phone rang".

Reference: https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html

Comment: Compare _The phone rang while I was getting ready to go out_ (continuous action interrupted) with _As she had dressed earlier, my wife looked up our route on the street plan while I got ready to go out_ (two actions happening concurrently).

Comment: It is the same for *joking*. Tom's belief is that the narrator began a joke, but  then Tom said he did not believe the story, before the narrator finished. Therefore, "joking" is a continuing event during the time that Tom said he did not believe it.

Comment: I've seen expressions such as "You jest!" (joke) and "You lie!" in texts from several centuries ago, but today we would always say "You're joking" and "You're lying".